# Error (generated new empty list) after edit data with React, Redux, and Redux Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Im facing problem when edit data with react and redux. The problem is **when i go to edit form, then submit, automatic generate a new empty list** like this(image below)

[image: Error on empty list]

Error on console:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

When i check in database, its normal and not add new empty data. Also when i refresh page, back to normal and no error, and the empty list go away.

These are some of my code:

actions/cityActions.js

```
export const editCity = (id, formValues) => async dispatch => {
 const response = await ws.patch(`/api/cities/${id}`, formValues);
 dispatch({
  type: EDIT_CITY,
  payload: response.data
 });
 history.push("/");
};
```

components/CityEdit.js

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCity, editCity } from "../../actions/cityActions";
import CityForm from "./CityForm";

class CityEdit extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCity(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
  onSubmit = formValues => {
    this.props.editCity(this.props.match.params.id, formValues);
  };
  render() {
    if (!this.props.city) {
      return <div>...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Edit a City</h3>
        <CityForm
          initialValues={_.pick(this.props.city, "name", "description")}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { city: state.cities[ownProps.match.params.id] };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCity, editCity })(CityEdit);
```

components/CityForm.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

class CityForm extends React.Component {
  renderError({ error, touched }) {
    if (error && touched) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger mt-1" role="alert">
          {error}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  renderInput = ({ input, label, meta, type, rows }) => {
    const className = `field ${meta.error && meta.touched ? "error" : ""}`;
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          {...input}
          autoComplete="off"
          type={type}
          rows={rows}
        />
        {this.renderError(meta)}
      </div>
    );
  };

  onSubmit = formValues => {
    this.props.onSubmit(formValues);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <Field
              name="name"
              component={this.renderInput}
              label="City Name"
              type="text"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <Field
              name="description"
              component={this.renderInput}
              label="Description"
              type="textarea"
              rows="7"
            />
          </div>

          <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const validate = formValues => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!formValues.name) {
    errors.name = "You must add a name";
  }
  if (!formValues.description) {
    errors.description = "You must add a description";
  }
  return errors;
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "cityForm",
  validate
})(CityForm);
```

reducers/cityReducer.js

```
import _ from "lodash";
import {
  FETCH_CITY,
  FETCH_CITIES,
  CREATE_CITY,
  EDIT_CITY,
  DELETE_CITY
} from "../actions/types";

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_CITIES:
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, "_id") };
    case FETCH_CITY:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case CREATE_CITY:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case EDIT_CITY:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case DELETE_CITY:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

complete code in my github https://github.com/hidjrie/ws

Sorry my bad English, feel free to edit my post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep some initial state inside your Reducer. Then you should consider the payload that you are getting from your Action. From the call

```
const response = await ws.patch(`/api/cities/${id}`, formValues);
```

Check if you are getting the only edited document/data as the output or the whole array of cities which includes the new data. If you are getting the only edit city-data then you will have to find the city from the city array inside the reducer and edit it. If not you can just replace the whole array with the new cities array returned by the database. But going through you Source code in Github it looks like from the City Update rest call you are not returning an array of data instead you are returning something like this
 `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }` Which does not include any id or data. So when you reducer receives this data it will append to it and therefore there will be an object inside your city array which doesn't have any property like id name etc. Ther fore you will get any city data entry in your list which will be empty.

For this try changing your `updateOne` to `findByIdAndUpdate` with the flag `{lean: true}`. This will return the object. and make sure you make necessary changes in your reducer to handle this.